# Windows Cannot find C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.exe in Win7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, microsoft-office-2010

I just installed Microsoft Office 2010 x64
But when I want to open it this error appears :

```
Windows Cannot find 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and try again.
```

I'm dead sure the file exist. 
How can I fix it?

P.S:
-I recently edit the registry manually, before installing MS Office 2010 
-I deleted some registry keys (20 to 25 reg keys).
-In addition, in opening some of other programs the same error has occurred.

Comment: You're sure you have 64-bit Office installed?  It's not at `C:\Program Files (x86)\ `?

Comment: Incase no one has told ya, it is a good idea to backup the registry before messing with it.  Regedit has an export function. Takes two seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I reinstall Windows and the problem has been solved.

Comment: XDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, especially this:

> I went to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14`, but when I execute Winword.exe` the error occur

And this:

> -I recently edit the registry manually, before installing MS Office 2010
>
> -I deleted some registry keys (20 to 25 reg keys).
>
> -In addition, in opening some of other programs the same error has occurred.

I'd venture to guess you hosed something up in your registry, especially if the other programs worked before you started editing.  If that's the case, you'll have to restore from a System Restore point (assuming you haven't disabled it) to a time before you made the edits, and see if that helps.

Since you commented that you don't have system restore enabled, then it sounds like your best course of action is to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately I disabled `System Restore` :-(

Comment: Well, sounds like you're looking at backing up your data and reinstalling.  Editing the registry can be a dangerous thing, and from the sounds of it, you're finding that out firsthand.

Comment: The things people will do to "optimize" their system . . .

Answer (score 0):

I would try making a new shortcut, and seeing if that fixes it.

The location of the current default shortcut in the Start Menu is here:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Word 2010.lnk
```

I would also test by going to that directory, `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\`, and executing Winword.exe directly.

Comment: I went to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\`, but when I execute `Winword.exe` the error occur

Comment: Was there a previous version of Office on the computer?

Comment: @: KCotreau : NO

Comment: OK, last question what, in general did you delete from the registry, and where was it? In HKLM or HKCU? If in HKLM, you might just be out of luck, but if in HKCU, I would create a new user and try that one, and if it works, I would copy the profile data off, and make a new profile.

Comment: Actually, there may be one more tool you can try to fix broken registry stuff: The Microsoft Readiness Tool. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20858 It can take up to two hours to run.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the right folder? I have x64 Windows 7 also, and it appears Office is x86, and installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12

Comment: @Simon Sheehan We are running the 64-bit version of Office. You are running a 32-bit version of Office 2007, it appears. We are not talking about 64-bit Windows, but Office only. Office 2010 is the first version of Office to come in both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, and the 64-bit version installs into the native C:\Program Files directory.